# Accessing web interfaces not possible

Tags: firewall, google-compute-engine, web-access

I've setup a two node hadoop instance on google compute engine. I got an dynamic external ip address which is `108.59.84.14`. I also did setup a proper hadoop configuration so the standard hadoop yarn ports are used which are for instance 8088 (the web interface for the Resource­Manager Web UI).

For granting external access I ran the following command (contains standard ports for hadoop stuff):

```
gcutil addfirewall web --network=hadoop-access --allowed=tcp:8088,tcp:50060,tcp:50070,tcp:50075,tcp:50090,tcp:20000,tcp:20001 --project=<project>
```

Now, after having started hadoop and after having checked that everything works fine:

```
hadoop@namenode:~$ jps
8057 NameNode
8451 ResourceManager
8164 DataNode
8544 NodeManager
8306 SecondaryNameNode
8835 Jps
```

I'd like to access the web interface. To do so I open up chrome browsr and enter `108.59.84.14:port` where port is for instance 8088. However, none of the ports work. I always get an error message which states that this page does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What image are you using ? I've encountered a similar problem on CentOS : you have to change the iptables rules too.

Comment: It's also worth double-checking that the network you've added the firewall rules to is the same as the network this instance is on. Are you comfortable sharing the output of gcutil getinstance for the instance in question?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities; you may want to try using the tcpdump tool to determine which of these cases you've hit.  When using tcpdump, remember to restrict to port 8088 with e.g. `tcpdump -vv port 8088`.

1. The GCE firewall is blocking the traffic.  This could be due to the firewall being applied to the wrong network (as Benson suggests).  You could determine this with tcpdump; no traffic should show up on the instance when trying to connect.
2. Your image may have a Linux firewall that's blocking traffic.  For this and the following case, you should see request packets arrive on 8088, followed by either a TCP RST (reset) or no response traffic.  In the case of no response, this is almost certainly a Linux firewall.
3. The hadoop software may only be listening on localhost.  In this case, you will see a TCP RST, you can tell the difference between this and the above case by running `netstat -lpn -A inet` to list all the listening programs and what address they are listening on.